# how to combine an id div and a php id

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I don't know the specifications of PHP and an ID DIV. Here's my question :

Can I put in the same time an **ID DIV** named ***#modal*** and an **ID PHP RETURN** ?

```
while ( $contents_print = mysqli_fetch_array( $req_print ) ) {  
    echo'
        <div class="row print">
            <div class="col s12 m4">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                  <img data-tags="print" class="activator" src="../00_sources/images/upload/pic_min/' . $contents_print[ 'pic_min' ] . '" alt="' . $contents_print[ 'pic_min' ] . '">
                  <a href="#modal" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light primary-color-text modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title">'.$contents_print['nom_projet'].'</span>
                  <p>'.$contents_print['detail_projet'].'</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>';
}
```

This is my jquery ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.materialboxed').materialbox();
 });

$( document ).ready( function () {
    $.ajax( {
            url: 'core/libs/contents-services.php?action=getFilterContent&id=3',
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function ( reponse ) {
                $( '#modal' ).html( reponse );
            }
        } );

    // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $( '.modal' ).modal();
} );
```

In my ajax code : the line **url: 'core/libs/contents-services.php?action=getFilterContent&id=3',** I have to use the id from the php/mysql request

I would like to make a link like this :
**url: 'core/libs/contents-services.php?action=getFilterContent&id='.$_GET['id'].',**

I hope I'am clear

Thanks for your help

http://portfolio.rabahbook.fr to see my working's site

Comment: `&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>`

Comment: Something like this <a href="#modal&id='.$contents_print['id_projet'].'>

Comment: What is the issue you are facing when you apply that code?

Comment: what you get in response variable?

Comment: the id is empty

Comment: the id shows corresponding's id, but the click action doesn't react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.post .modal-action').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_projet= $(this).data('id_projet');
    var $hidennDiv = $('#' +id_projet);
    // do your ajax and whatever you want to do with the hidden div
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'core/libs/contents-services.php?action=getFilterContent&id='+id_projet,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function ( reponse ) {
            $( '#modal' ).html( reponse );
            id_projet = reponse.id_projet;
        }
    } );
    $( '.modal' ).modal();
});
```

This works for me

```
<a href="#modal" class="modal-action modal-trigger" data-id_projet="'.$contents_print[ 'id_projet' ].'"></a>
```

Thanks all to taking time to anwser to me !

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you get an Id from response and trying to assign it to ajax href. If this is your case, you can do something as below(please note the url_id variable.):

```
var url_id =3;

$( document ).ready( function () {
$.ajax( {
  url: 'core/libs/contents-services.php?action=getFilterContent&id='+url_id,
  type: "get",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function ( reponse ) {
     $( '#modal' ).html( reponse );
     url_id  = response.url_id;/// get url id from response and assign it to 
     //your  href
  }
});

 // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID 
 //that wants to be triggered
 $( '.modal' ).modal();
 } );
 </script>
```

Comment: This code is not bad at all ! But the things is that i'am not able to get the id's corresponding to the mysql request. When i click on the **href** link i want to the id and the modal id together. In this  way i can print different informations in a popup called #modal. May be i don't explain very well